# Joomla 2.5 Purge Expired doesn't work

Tags: php, joomla2.5, cache-control

I'm using joomla 2.5, about 2 days ago Purge Expired button stoped working.

When I click Purge Expired, page refreshes and becomes blank... but before it did work fine.

What could cause such behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Please check your server `error_logs`.

Comment: I have a warning about ffmpeg and another warning about JomSocial. Nothing connected to the issue...